# Is there any way to get a lru list in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, memory, kernel

I want to get a LRU list of zone.

I used lruvec in Zone struct and access lists in lruvec

Like this,

```
list_For_each(curr, &zone->lruvec.lists[LRU_INACTIVE_FILE])
list_for_each(curr, &zone->lruvec.lists[LRU_ACTIVE_FILE])
```

But, this loop didn't work cause lruvec's lists are empty.

I checked that lruvec was filled with some data linux kernel source code on memory(src/mm.c or include/linux/mm).

But I don't know how can I access and get the LRU list (active/inactive file)

Please help me, I can't solve ..